# minimal description of polyhedron

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, polyhedra

I have to find minimal description of a polyhedron $P$ described as follows:

\begin{align*}x_1 -  x_2 &\leq 0\\-x_1 + x_2 &\leq 1\\2x_2 & \leq 5 \\ 4x_1 - x_2 &\leq 8 \\ x_1 + x_2 &\geq 1\\x_1 &\geq 0, x_2 \geq 0.\end{align*}

So far I have managed to get: \begin{align*}x_1 -  x_2 &\leq 0\\-x_1 + x_2 &\leq 1\\2x_2 & \leq 5 .\end{align*}

Can anyone tell me if that is correct?

Comment: Your constraints would allow $(x_1,x_2) = (1/4, 1/2)$, but that point isn't feasible.

Comment: Indeed you omitted the nonnegativity constraints, $x_1,x_2 \ge 0$, which would allow the point $(x_1,x_2) = (-1,-1)$ to satisfy your reduced set of constraints (but not the original ones).  The nonnegativity constraints are needed to make the feasible region bounded.

Comment: Would it be correct if I just add to my minimal description: $-x_1 - x_2\leq -1$ ?

Comment: @hardmath The nonnegativity constraints are redundant, as they are implied by $x_1+x_2\geq1$ along with the first two constraints.

Comment: @Lukas: I don't know how you approached the problem, but I would graph these constraints and find the minimal number of edges that way.  Since only two variables are involved, we really looking at a convex *polygon* rather than a polyhedron.

Comment: @hardmath Right; my point is that including the nonnegativity constraints to the "reduced set" still does not solve the problem. In any case, yes, graphing the constraints is the way to go.

Comment: @Lukas I´ve sketched the feasible region and I´ve evaluated that you need 4 constraints. No non-negativity constraint is needed.

Comment: @Lukas See [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYtOQ.jpg) with fieasible region.